# Load AMPScript from an asset outside Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I have an asset within Marketing Cloud that includes Ampscript. This asset fetches and retrieves info from a Data Extension. I want to include that asset within an existing site and such asset to display the info retrieved from the Data Extension.

Is there any way to make this asset to preload the ampscript code and be retrieved containing the desired text and not the code?

By costumer limitations, we can't use any framework. We are currently using PHP and this is the code used to fetch the asset:

```
$curl = curl_init();
$asset_id = "xxxxx";
$url  = "https://www.exacttargetapis.com/asset/v1/content/assets"; 
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "$url/$asset_id",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        "Authorization: Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    ),
));
```

and this is part of the code of the asset:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="carousel slide" id="carousel-922619">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-slide-to="0" data-target="#carousel-922619" class="active"></li>
            <li data-slide-to="1" data-target="#carousel-922619"></li>
            <li data-slide-to="2" data-target="#carousel-922619"></li>
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
                <img class="d-block w-100" alt="Carousel Bootstrap First" src="https://dummyimage.com/610x250/08e/ffffff&text=Similac+CO+1" height="250">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h4 class="Text">



                        %%[
                            set @rows = LookupRows("DE_NAME","COL_NAME", "COL_VALUE_TO_LOOKUP")
                            set @rowCount = rowcount(@rows)
                        ]%%



                    </h4>
                    <p class="Text">
                        Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img class="d-block w-100" alt="Carousel Bootstrap Second" src="https://dummyimage.com/610x250/50e/ffffff&text=Similac+CO+2" height="250">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h4 class="Text">
                        Second Thumbnail label
                    </h4>
                    <p class="Text">
                        Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img class="d-block w-100" alt="Carousel Bootstrap Third" src="https://dummyimage.com/610x250/580/ffffff&text=Similac+CO+3" height="250">
                <div class="carousel-caption"> 
                    <h4 class="Text">
                        Third Thumbnail label
                    </h4>
                    <p class="Text">
                        Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carousel-922619" data-slide="prev"><span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span> <span class="sr-only">Previous</span></a> <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carousel-922619" data-slide="next"><span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span> <span class="sr-only">Next</span></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Appreciate your help, regards.

Answer (score 0):

If your AMPScript code snippet is not complex as in your example(Just LookupRows), you can put all that AMPScript code into a Cloudpage. Then, you can call the result of that page with iframe.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but for business requirements, we are not able to use iframes. That was my first though also, but trying to find some other way. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You can do what Selim Sevim mentioned and add the full HTML & AMPScript inside a CloudPage. Then in your PHP page just retrieve the contents of the Cloud Page

`$cloudPage = file_get_contents("URL_TO_CLOUDPAGE");`

AMPScript can only be processed within an Email or CloudPage in Marketing Cloud so this is the only way to do it.